# How to force users to change their Windows Hello Pin

Tags: active-directory, entra-id, microsoft-intune

We changed our password policy in the Microsoft Endpoint Manager and now require a longer PIN.

The issue is, in testing we noticed you're only asked to change the Windows Hello PIN, when logging in with it.
Since many of our users use biometric logins, they aren't asked to change it.

I'm looking for a solution where the user is asked to change the PIN regardless of the sign-in method. Just like when the PIN expires.